# Can't put bounty on own question (can't see the button with time left)

Tags: support, bounties

I recall that before the 2 days that need to elapse before a bounty can be assigned, there was a button for it, anyway. Can't see it now in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786507/cant-access-svc-files-in-wcf-services-after-deployment). Am I going madly blind (or maybe blindly mad)?!

Comment: Can you post screenshot? You should see "this question is eligible for bounty in..."

Comment: Can you see that button ("this question is eligible for bounty in...") on this question?

Comment: I can't see the bounty button on this question nor on the OP's question on SO. Can you see it, @hims056?

Comment: @Antony - No I too can't see it anywhere.

Comment: @hims056 only the OP of the question can see the message (it's not a button, it's a link) and it's by design. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, I wasn't looking at the right place. I remembered that the bounty button was right below the question but it seems it's below the comments. I got a problem with vision due due a brain tumor but this time it was probably just a temporary confusion.   :)

Comment: Cheers, no harm done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you got me worried so I made a quick test. The message is stil there, but not as button. It's rather a link to the [proper section of the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> [image]

Comment: And how did you perform this test? :)

Comment: @Antony - Asked [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189954/187824) and deleted.

Comment: Seems the blood that the OP is crying has obscured his vision. :-)

Comment: @hims056 how did you find it?? ;-)

Comment: ...voting to undelete...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - From the active questions list. :P I tried to vote but you deleted instantly.

Comment: @hims056 darned cache! :D

Comment: @Bart nooooooooooooooooo

Comment: Maybe we need sandbox site with same codebase as Stack Overflow where we can go wild and test everything? :-)

Comment: Yeah! We could call it Meta Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Cody and its logo will be unicorn!

Comment: @Sha - Yeah! We can't ask a question in [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/187824).

Comment: @hims056 the Formatting sandbox is so 2012! :D